# Data use only hour minute seconte

Tags: android, date

Im working on android and parse some XML file
I get some date with this

```
DateFormat h = new SimpleDateFormat ("hh:mm:ss", Locale.FRANCE);
DateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-M-dd'T'hh:mm:ss", Locale.FRANCE);
Date hdebut = h.parse(maString);
```

Probleme is Date is for Date not hour so it give me a 1 january 1970(start of timestamp right?) a the correct our so i can't compare by using

```
Date now  new Date();
now.after(hdebut);
```

i have some method to getHours or month but they are decrepetead so i don't know if i can use them or if wa have a better way no to do it

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
```

Try this. There are a lot of constants you can use with [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) class.

Answer (score 2):

`Date` is deprecated. You should be using [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instead.
`Calendar` provides working `after` and `before` methods as well and should work with pretty much any date you'll get to use :).

Comment: :O the class Date is deprecated is was thinking it's only was for some members function thank for advice i will look the Calendar class